# Нужно ли заменить частицу "не" частицей "ни"?

Tags: безграмотность

"...И сколько б ты не жил, в какой бы не был силе,

```
И кто бы не склонял тебя на все лады,

И сколько б не вело следов к твоей могиле -

Дождь смоет все следы, дождь смоет все следы."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В придаточных частях сложноподчиненных предложений следует различать сочетания ***кто бы ни, что бы ни, где бы ни, какой бы ни, сколько бы ни и др. с*** частицей *ни,* примыкающей к относительному слову, и сочетания ***кто бы не, что бы не, где бы не, какой бы не, сколько бы не и др. с частицей не,*** относящейся к сказуемому. В первом случае передается обобщенный смысл, ни усиливает утверждение, во втором — отрицание не стоит при сказуемом в отрицательном предложении; ср.: Кто бы к нему ни обращался, всякий получал дельный совет. — Нет никого, кто бы к нему не обращался за советом; Равнодушный человек не мог бы так петь, каким бы он ни обладал голосом (Айтм.); Человек должен трудиться, кто бы он ни был. ( Грамма.ру).

В вашем предложении передается обобщенный смысл, поэтому здесь будет верно употребить частицу ***ни***.

Comment: С п а с и б о

Answer (score 2):

Всюду надо заменить частицу "не" частицей "ни". Почему? "Не жил" - прямое отрицание, которого по смыслу в этой фразе нет. Точно так же следует рассматривать все остальные глаголы с частицей

Comment: Б л а г о д а р ю